# How to escape \triangle, \bold etc while finding patterns in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string that goes like:

```
\triangle \bold \new \regex
```

I have used `(re.findall(r"\\\w+",s)` but it is not giving me results because it obviously does not recognize `\t, \b` etc. as the way I want it. How can I escape those characters?

I am using variables to store the string so I **CAN NOT** do `s = r'\triangle \bold'`. I used `repr('\triangle \bold')` as a workaround but it gives me `'\\triangle','\\x08oldsymbol'`.

What is the way out for these situations?

Anything like `\\triangle, \\bold` or `\triangle, \bold` is something that I am expecting.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: @imraklr I have updated the desired results

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> txt = r"\triangle \bold \new \regex"   #Notice the leading r
>>> txt
'\\triangle \\bold \\new \\regex'
>>> txt.split('\\')
['', 'triangle ', 'bold ', 'new ', 'regex']
```

Comment: Notice how he said in his question that he can not just define the string as raw, which is exactly what you do.

Comment: You're right. But, I didn't get the point why he can't.

Comment: The problem is that once the string is escaped, when you unescape it the backspace  character ```\b``` remains escaped. He is dealing with a string that is already escaped.

Comment: @daktoad Exactly my point. My strings are inside a Variable. Is there a way to make them **RAW** within the variable? I have o use that regex live so manually defining them raw is not an option, at all.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is just a work around, but you can rebuild your string from scratch. Try this:

```
import re

string = "\triangle \bold \new \regex"


escape_dict = {
    '\a' : r'\a',
    '\b' : r'\b',
    '\c' : r'\c',
    '\f' : r'\f',
    '\n' : r'\n',
    '\r' : r'\r',
    '\t' : r'\t',
    '\v' : r'\v',
    '\'' : r'\'',
    '\"' : r'\"'
}

def raw(string):
    new_string = ""
    for char in string:
        try: 
            new_string += escape_dict[char]
        except KeyError: 
            new_string += char
    return new_string

matches = re.findall(r"\\\w+", raw(string))
print(matches)
```

However, I would see if maybe you can maybe change something earlier on in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you are using the variable `s` to store string and you are not using `r` prefix in it. So there is one problem. If you have `\u` or `\x` or `\U` or `\N` in your string then a `SyntaxError` will be raised.
For example:

```
>>> s = 'There is no way o\ut'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 17-18: truncated \uXXXX escape
>>> s = 'Cross symbol(\x) says it is wrong'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 13-14: truncated \xXX escape
>>> s = 'What an escape Seque\Nce'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 20-21: malformed \N character escape
>>> s = 'What an escape Seq\Uence'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 18-20: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

So if i assume that your string has no `\u` or `\x` or `\U` or `\N` then you can try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> def repEsc(s):
        s = re.sub('\a', r'\\a', s)
        s = re.sub('\b', r'\\b', s)
        s = re.sub('\f', r'\\f', s)
        s = re.sub('\v', r'\\v', s)
        s = re.sub('\n', r'\\n', s)
        s = re.sub('\r', r'\\r', s)
        s = re.sub('\t', r'\\t', s)
        return s
>>> s = '\triangle \bold \new \regex'
>>> s = repEsc(s)
>>> s
'\\triangle \\bold \\new \\regex'
>>> print(s)
\triangle \bold \new \regex
```